# Поиск и замена текста с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо в видимом пользователю html документе найти определенные текстовые последовательности и отформатировать их.

Необходимо заменить все строки вида `id:6774076|PRODUCT|123D` на идентичные, но значение id оформлен как ссылка с параметрами

Как это можно сделать с помощью jquery?

Пробовал что-то типо этого:

HTML:

```
...
        <tr>
                <th scope="row">322</th>
                <td>OK</td>
                <td><pre>Текст id:6774076|PRODUCT|123D текст  
                         текст текст текст текст текст текст 
                         текст текст текст текст текст текст 
                         текст текст текст 
                         текст id:224076|CATEGORY|123D
                    </pre>
                </td>
            </tr>
...
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).find('body').each(function () {

            let old_html = $(this).html();
            let regexp = /id:(\w+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)/gm;
            let to_replace = [];

            match = regexp.exec(old_html);
            while (match != null) {
                let id= match[1];
                let obj= match[2];
                let element= match[3];

                if (obj=== 'CATEGORY') {
                    to_replace.push({
                        'from': match[0],
                        'to': 'id:<a href="/category?id=' + id + '&element=' + element+ '">' + id + '</a>|' + obj + '|' + element
                    })
                }
                match = regexp.exec(old_html);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < to_replace.length; i++) {
                old_html.replace(to_replace[i].from,to_replace[i].to)
            }
        });

       $(this).html(old_html)

    })
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему измененный html не сохраняется и не отображается?

Comment: забить текст в строку, найти в строке что вам нужно заменить с помощью регулярок, и потом заменить на что вам нужно.

Comment: потому что `replace` **возвращает новую строку** а не меняет старую